# Twitterizer Hashtags and metions search

Tags: search, twitter, twitterizer

I would like to do a search in twitterzer that allows me to get all the tweets with a particular hashtag mentioning a particular user on twitter. I used the .Search method but it only works for one query word (a mention or a Hashtag but no both). is that possible?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The Search method allows a string as input, so you're not limited to one word.

```
 TwitterResponse<TwitterSearchResultCollection> searchResults = TwitterSearch.Search("#thisis40 to:conanobrien");
```

If you are not sure about the syntax of the query, you can use the [advanced search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced) on the Twitter website. Just fill in your parameters and copy the query.

[image]